# Linear Algebra , matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A = [a_{ij}]$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix such that $\det(A) =-6$.
If matrix $B$ is defined by
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}3a_{33} & 3a_{32} & 3a_{31} \\
    2\left(a_{31}+a_{23}\right)  & 2\left(a_{12}+a_{22}\right) & 2\left(a_{11}+a_{21}\right) \\
    a_{23} & a_{22} & a_{21}\end{bmatrix}$$

evaluate $\det(B)$

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Do you know how determinants relate to the elementary row operations?

Comment: Also, make sure I edited the question correctly.

Comment: HI yes i do. And yes it is correctly edited

Comment: Then have you tried doing elementary row(/column) operations on $\det(B)$ until you get it into the form $\left| \begin{array}{cc} a_{11} & \cdots \\ \vdots & \ddots \end{array} \right|$?

Comment: Will try that now

Comment: If you can't get it, let me know and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Will do for sure

Comment: Hi i just did it. i dont think its right. im getting it as 0

Comment: Are you sure that $b_{21}$ shouldn't be $2(a_{\mathbf{13}}+a_{23})$?  As written, I don't think this is solvable.

Comment: I just copied whatever was in the question

Comment: Below I posted my answer assuming that that one spot was a misprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\det(B) &= \left|\begin{array}{ccc}3a_{33} & 3a_{32} & 3a_{31} \\
    2\left(a_{13}+a_{23}\right)  & 2\left(a_{12}+a_{22}\right) & 2\left(a_{11}+a_{21}\right) \\
    a_{23} & a_{22} & a_{21}\end{array}\right|\\ &= (3)(2)\left|\begin{array}{ccc}a_{33} & a_{32} & a_{31} \\
    \left(a_{13}+a_{23}\right)  & \left(a_{12}+a_{22}\right) & \left(a_{11}+a_{21}\right) \\
    a_{23} & a_{22} & a_{21}\end{array}\right| & \begin{pmatrix} R_1 \to \frac 13R_1 \\ R_2 \to \frac 12R_2\end{pmatrix} \\ &= 6\left|\begin{array}{ccc}a_{33} & a_{32} & a_{31} \\
    a_{13}  & a_{12} & a_{11} \\
    a_{23} & a_{22} & a_{21}\end{array}\right| & \begin{pmatrix} R_2 \to R_2 - R_3\end{pmatrix} \\ &= -6\left|\begin{array}{ccc} a_{23} & a_{22} & a_{21} \\
    a_{13}  & a_{12} & a_{11} \\
    a_{33} & a_{32} & a_{31}\end{array}\right| & \begin{pmatrix} R_1 \leftrightarrow R_3\end{pmatrix} \\ &= 6\left|\begin{array}{ccc} a_{13}  & a_{12} & a_{11} \\
    a_{23} & a_{22} & a_{21} \\
    a_{33} & a_{32} & a_{31}\end{array}\right| & \begin{pmatrix} R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2\end{pmatrix} \\ &= -6\left|\begin{array}{ccc} a_{11}  & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\end{array}\right| & \begin{pmatrix} C_1 \leftrightarrow C_3\end{pmatrix} \\ &= -6\det(A) \\ &= 36\end{align}$$